# Simulation time in Omnet++

Tags: java, omnet++, inet

I'm using the Omnetpp-5.6.1 and I want get the time simulation. I'm using tic toc example, and when I put the function `simTime()`, it only returns 0. My code is like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>


using namespace omnetpp;

/**
 * Derive the Txc1 class from cSimpleModule. In the Tictoc1 network,
 * both the `tic' and `toc' modules are Txc1 objects, created by OMNeT++
 * at the beginning of the simulation.
 */
class Txc1 : public cSimpleModule
{
  protected:
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

// The module class needs to be registered with OMNeT++
Define_Module(Txc1);

void Txc1::initialize()
{
    if (strcmp("source", getName()) == 0) {
        // create and send first message on gate "out". "tictocMsg" is an
        // arbitrary string which will be the name of the message object.

        cMessage *msg = new cMessage("tictocMsg");

        send(msg, "out");

    }
}

void Txc1::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{

    EV<< msg->getSendingTime()<< Simtime() ;
    send(msg, "out"); // send out the message

}
```

I found this function [here](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1SimTime.html#a6955edd3381bf4735c83f3d4285f1356) but I don't know how to use it.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

In some Tic Toc examples there is neither delay in a channel nor delay in processing a message, therefore everything may happen at t=0.
Take a look whether in your example there is a delay in channels or there is `scheduleAt()` with future time in the C++ code.

Comment: Ahh okay, i didn't know how this function worked. But i need one function, for example, i send a message for one node, and i need get the time the message is send and the message arrival, but need is the exactly time, because with these times i calculate the position of node. I see the function getSendingTime, but not worked correctly. Have one solution for this?

Comment: Could you show the code in which you are using `getSendingTime()`?

Comment: Yes, i edit my question with all code in Tx1.cc, take a look